# Extended position start date. How to extend it again while waiting for waiver?

Tags: job-search, job, assistant-professor, visa

I was on a Fulbright in the US during my Ph.D., and returned to my country upon completion of my studies. I was in the US on a J1 visa, which requires that you return to your home country for two years at the end of the visa.

I was offered an assistant professor position in the US and accepted it. Then I applied for a [J1 2-year waiver](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/study/exchange/waiver-of-the-exchange-visitor.html). The start date of the position was August 2019, However, I am still waiting for the decision of the waiver. In the meantime, the department extended my start date to Jan 2020. Also the department chair said that they may not extend it again and the position may even be lost.

How do you think I can make my offer guaranteed or maybe increase my chances of extending the start date once again until I can obtain a waiver or fulfill my 2-year home residency by August 2020. This is the perfect job for me and the department is very supportive. Should I offer to teach in the spring for free to plead another extension? Thanks!

Comment: Surely teaching (for free or not) at the US institution during your home residency period would not count as being in your home country? Or am I misunderstanding your intention?

Comment: Teaching at the department remotely while I am in my home country so I can show my involvement, my competency and spend some time so they can negotiate with/demonstrate the upper-level units at the University.

Comment: @ZoeyBarman, I've suggested an edit to make the requirements of the J1 visa clearer, for those that aren't familiar with it.

Comment: @DCTLib ok, wasn't too clear prior to the edit, will delete my comment.